How to prevent new users with old Android devices from downloading my App?
Due to third party sdk constraints, I want to prevent users with devices older than Android 8.0 from downloading my app.
However, I already have an app version 1.0.1 with minimum SDK 24 published on the Play Store. What happens when I release a new app version 1.0.2 with minimum SDK 26?
I know that current users with Android 7.0 can still use app version 1.0.1 but can't upgrade to 1.0.2
My question is:
Can new users using Android 7.0 still see the old version 1.0.1 on the Play Store? If so, how do I prevent them from downloading my app?

You should make min sdk to 26 then generate bundle and upload it and while uploading choose option rollout 100%

To my knowledge Google Play Store does not provide older versions to new users on devices that do no longer meet the minimum device criteria of a new app version (in difference to Apple App Store). However users may download old app versions from third party APK download sites. The best way to prevent usage of old app versions is checking the app version on your server (assuming the app is not 100% offline) or integrate a "lastest app version check" into the app that enforces the users to update.

Something like
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    mainActivity.finish();
}

should do the job which i dont recommend actually.
if you change your minSdk in build.grade (app) your app will be automatically filtered
